# How does Lc3 division work

Tags: assembly, lc3

Ive been trying to figure out how the division by subtraction works but there are no resources online that make it clear. Also i need a good example of how subroutines should look like in terms of syntax.

Comment: What is your (specific) question?

Comment: Division by repeated subtraction is pretty straightforward.  Just think it through: subtract the divisor repeatedly, and count how many times you looped.  Just like multiplying by adding in a loop.

Comment: That part I understand it's the remainder part where I draw a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can approach division in LC3. If you're looking for an example on how to do division through subtraction take a look at this post:

[How do i do a bitshift right in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942014/how-do-i-do-a-bitshift-right-in-binary)

But if you don't have to use the subtraction method, I would recommend doing 15 bit-shifts to the left. It's more efficient because it requires less run time, and its speed isn't impacted by the number we want to bit shift.

---

The code below shows you how to preform a bit-shift right by using 15 bit shifts to the left:

```
.ORIG x3000
LD R0, VALUE

SHIFT_RIGHT
    AND R2, R2, #0              ; Clear R2, used as the loop counter

    SR_LOOP
        ADD R3, R2, #-15        ; check to see how many times we've looped
        BRzp SR_END             ; If R2 - 15 = 0 then exit

        LD R3, BIT_15           ; load BIT_15 into R3
        AND R3, R3, R0          ; check to see if we'll have a carry
        BRz #3                  ; If no carry, skip the next 3 lines
        ADD R0, R0, R0          ; bit shift left once
        ADD R0, R0, #1          ; add 1 for the carry
        BRnzp #1                ; skip the next line of code
        ADD R0, R0, R0          ; bit shift left

        ADD R2, R2, #1          ; increment our loop counter
        BRnzp SR_LOOP           ; start the loop over again
    SR_END

    ST R0, ANSWER               ; we've finished looping 15 times, store R0
    HALT

BIT_15      .FILL   b1000000000000000
VALUE       .FILL   x3BBC       ; some random number we want to bit shift right
ANSWER      .BLKW   1

.END
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example: 23/8, which we expect to return 2 remainder 7.

```
Set NUM=23 and DIVISOR=8, initializing DIVIDEND=0 and REMAINDER=0
Loop as long as NUM > DIVISOR:
   NUM = NUM - DIVISOR decreases the overall number
   DIVIDEND = DIVIDEND + 1 because we've discovered that it fits once more
```

At the end, REMAINDER = NUM because that's the number that could no longer have another DIVISOR subtracted from it when the loop terminates

So, let's walk through this an iteration at a time:

```
0) NUM=23, DIVIDEND=0
1) (23 > 8, continue) NUM=23-8=15, DIVIDEND=0+1=1
2) (15 > 8, continue) NUM=15-8=7, DIVIDEND=1+1=2
3) (8 < 7, stop)
```

Final answers, REMAINDER=NUM=7, DIVIDEND=2